# How to post to a Facebook page with PHP

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, access-token

I would like to post to my own Facebook page's wall from my website using PHP.

I have the following:

- **Facebook Application** with AppID, AppSecret, ApiKey
- **Facebook Page** with PageID
- **my own Facebook account** - I'm the admin and the creator of the application and page mentioned above.

E.g. I write a blog post, and I'd like to get the name, the short description and a picture on my Facebook page's wall. Or I would like to publish some articles on the Facebook page every day automatically as a cron job.

Could you provide a **step-by-step** tutorial how to accomplish this?

I've read this article about Facebook Login:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/
but I still don't know what to write in my code.

---

#### UPDATE 1

This is how I send a request for an App Access Token:

```
$url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?grant_type=client_credentials&client_id='
        .Yii::app()->params['FacebookAppID']
        .'&client_secret='
        .Yii::app()->params['FacebookSecret'];
```

The response is similar to this (fake symbols):

`access_token=326584076429|ax3-D39YbpDcR9rMRQn_fMvNu_s`

What `access_token` is it? Application Access Token? How to get a User Access Token?

I tried to use the access token from here:
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=me%2Faccounts
but I got the following error message:

> *An active access token must be used to query information about the current user*

So how should I obtain the right access token?

#### UPDATE 2:

How can I get the right Facebook tokens in my application without any client interaction?
I'm the admin and the creator of the Facebook Application and the Facebook Page.

Answer (score 10):

**Step by step**

1. Authenticate a user that is a page admin (yourself)
2. Request an extended access token (to get a 60 day variety as offline_access is gone). See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/offline-access-deprecation/
3. Call Graph API `me/accounts` and search thru the resulting list to find the page you're interested in
4. Take the page access token from the page and start using that for the calls to post
5. It might be possible to get an extended access token for a page access token like described in step 2, please try and let us know if that can be done for page access token too.

You can experiment with the above at https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer

Happy Coding!

**EDIT**

For getting an access token without dialogs for any user, you can use https://developers.facebook.com/tools/access_token/ to get an access token.

Comment: Thanks for answer. How `Authenticate a user that is a page admin` can be done? What data should I pass and where? Thanks. :)

Comment: I'm trying :) with no result. Please, see UPD1 in first post.

Comment: Thank you for showing some honest effort! Understanding the whole Facebook authentication can take a while (took me two solid days of pouring thru it to understand it...yeah I've got a thick head). That hard part of what you have is that you want it to be a cron job.  Which means you will have to come get a user access token from that graph explorer tool, then request the 60 day version (see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/offline-access-deprecation/) and then put that token into your cron-job code.  The better way is to ensure you authenticate using php each time you want to post.

Comment: :) So... do you know any way to authenticate from cron-job? Please, help :) How cron-script can post to facebook's page's wall?

Comment: It's the same problem in Windows environment. Is it possible to post to page's wall from any application?

Comment: Of course it is.  I have a production app the currently does this.  Both using a windows service (scheduled posting for marketing campaigns) as well as a user interactive posting.  When the user schedules the posting, I get a long-term access token for them, and store that with the scheduled posting.

Comment: What can I do with `App Access Token`? It looks like `access_token=326584076429|ax3-D39YbpDcR9rMRQn_fMvNu_s`. Can I obtain `Page Access Token`? Or what is the next move to post to Facebook's Page Wall?

Comment: Steps 1-4 will get you to having a PAGE access token.

Comment: :)) how can I do step number one? is it possible without browser? how? if you know the answer - please explain :) I don't get `how` can I authenticate page's admin? With `login` and `password`? With `Facebook App`? How? How? How? :)) Pleeeease!

Comment: I've already answered the original question before you modified it.  Please please please play by the rules and stop adding new questions and changing the original. You can use the Graph API Explorer tool to get an access token (https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer).

Comment: Or you can use https://developers.facebook.com/tools/access_token/ to get an access token.

Comment: What original question have you answered and where? Original question is `Can anyone explain, step-by-step, what actions should I do?` You answered `Authenticate a user that is a page admin (yourself)`. Is it normal answer? No! It can't help. I asked for details `HOW` can I authenticate as page's admin? If you know the answer - what's the problem to write here? I can pay for any working example. If you are here in this question thread and know the answer and have working example in any language - why you can't just post it?

Comment: Thanks for this link `https://developers.facebook.com/tools/access_token/`. but is it possible to get these access tokens from that link automatically?

Comment: No sorry not possible automatically.  You need to do the steps above.

Comment: After offline_access deprecation, will be possible to (automatically, of course) refresh the access token e.g. using a cron job without user interaction?

Comment: After the 60 days, Facebook requires the user to Re-interact with your app. Don't shoot me, I'm just reading what they wrote. From their documentation:  "If you would like to renew a still valid access_token, you will have to get a new client-side access token first and then call the same endpoint below.  Apps will not be able to setup a background/cron job that tries to automatically extend the expiration time, because the "authorization code" is short-lived and will have expired."

Comment: @DMCS thank you, i'm going to investigate further, this is really bad... i'm displaying insights data and forcing the user to authorize again is a pain (even if takes less than 3 secs...).

Answer (score 2):

Steps:

1. **Request For manage_pages permission ( Allow this process ) :**

   ```
   https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=YOUR_APP_ID&redirect_uri=YOUR_URL&scope=manage_pages&response_type=token
   ```
2. **Get Access token from URL :**
   If the administrator allows this permission. You should be redirected to URL below:

   ```
   http://YOUR_URL/#access_token=AAABY5jBXQz0BAEzNKkb6FZC22D7aOoKIfFuozIjoOpkGHRJ6SyzBvqx24JGooMc31374EdRFNXkOyLZCBzETRD9vhZAZC8MZD&expires_in=0
   ```

   Use **Access token** in the URL and you should get this:

   ```
   AAABY5jBXQz0BAEzNKkb6FZC22D7aOoKIfFuozIjoOpkGHRJ6SyzBvqx24JGooMc31374EdRFNXkOyLZCBzETRD9vhZAZC8MZD
   ```
3. **Check Access token using Graph API:**

   ```
   https://graph.facebook.com/me/accounts?access_token=TOKEN_FROM_ABOVE
   ```

   Connection will return information and access token for each page.
4. **Implement it in your code:**
   You can use App access token while call a Facebook Graph API method.

**Update:**
If you want use API method in Facebook SDK, *DEPRECATED* REST API or FQL Query...

You have to use **`users_accesstoken`** this way:

1. **Method 1:**
   Use your account or users to login to your Facebook page with offline_access permissions and grab access_token while login success using `$facebook->getAccessToken()`, and save it in database so you can use it anytime.
   You can check the expiration time of the token [here](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/access_token/), token with `offline_access` permissions never expire except when the user changes his password or maybe anything else.
2. **Method 2:**
   You can update your `access_token` dynamically using the code below (say goodbye to expire token). Facebook shows this solution [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/), it's a sample code for executing an FQL Query:

**Code:**

```
<?php
$app_id = 'YOUR_APP_ID';
$app_secret = 'YOUR_APP_SECRET';
$my_url = 'POST_AUTH_URL';
$code = $_REQUEST["code"];

//auth user
if(empty($code)) {
    $dialog_url = 'https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=' 
        . $app_id . '&redirect_uri=' . urlencode($my_url) ;
    echo("<script>top.location.href='" . $dialog_url . "'</script>");    
}

//get user access_token
$token_url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id='
. $app_id . '&redirect_uri=' . urlencode($my_url) 
. '&client_secret=' . $app_secret 
. '&code=' . $code;
$access_token = file_get_contents($token_url);
```

Comment: What is `redirect_uri=YOUR_URL` in first step? Script should run in automatic mode, with no user interaction. So, if I try to `CURL` this link - I got Facebook's login form. With no way to continue :)

Comment: Instead of `$code = $_REQUEST["code"];`, you should use `$code = isset($_REQUEST['code']) ? $_REQUEST['code'] : NULL;` not to get a PHP notice if `$_REQUEST['code']` is not set (depending on PHP `error_reporting`). And yes, it's bad that Facebook developer's site [shows a bad example](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/498/).

Answer (score 0):

Try this simple function to post onto a wall:

```php
function doWallPost($postName = '', $postMessage = '', $postLink = '', $postCaption = '', $postDescription = '') {
  $FB_APP_ID     = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
  $FB_APP_SECRET = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';

  $APP_RETURN_URL = ((substr($_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'], 0, 4) == "HTTP") ? "http://" : "https://") . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'];

  $code = $_REQUEST["code"];

  if (empty($code)) {
    $dialog_url = "http://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=" . $FB_APP_ID . "&redirect_uri=" . $APP_RETURN_URL . "&scope=publish_stream";
    header("Location:$dialog_url");
  }

  $token_url    = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=" . $FB_APP_ID . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode($APP_RETURN_URL) . "&client_secret=" . $FB_APP_SECRET . "&code=" . $code;
  $access_token = file_get_contents($token_url);

  $param1          = explode("&", $access_token);
  $param2          = explode("=", $param1[0]);
  $FB_ACCESS_TOKEN = $param2[1];


  $url        = "https://graph.facebook.com/me/feed";
  $attachment = array(
    'access_token' => $FB_ACCESS_TOKEN,
    'name' => $postName,
    'link' => $postLink,
    'description' => $postDescription,
    'message' => $postMessage,
    'caption' => $postCaption
  );

  $ch = curl_init();
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 2);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $attachment);
  $result = curl_exec($ch);
  header('Content-type:text/html');
  curl_close($ch);

  return $result;
}
```

Comment: I'm executing this script from cron-job, not from browser. So I can't do any approval in Facebook's popup dialogs because it isn't in browser :)

Comment: Instead of `$code = $_REQUEST["code"];`, you should use `$code = isset($_REQUEST['code']) ? $_REQUEST['code'] : NULL;` not to get a PHP notice if `$_REQUEST['code']` is not set (depending on PHP `error_reporting`). And yes, it's bad that Facebook developer's site [shows a bad example](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/498/).