# How to post on facebook fan page from a website with PHP?

Tags: php, facebook, access-token, facebook-access-token

I need to post an article right after the user create that on their backend.
I'm using sdk-php with this script:

```
require 'facebook-php-sdk/src/facebook.php';

$config = array(
    'appId' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
    'secret' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
    'allowSignedRequest' => false 
  );

  $facebook = new Facebook($config);
  $params = array(
  "access_token" => "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
  "message" => "Message",
  "link" => "http://www.myarticle.com",
  "picture" => "http://www.myarticle.com/img1.png",
  "name" => "Name",
  "caption" => "Caption",
  "description" => "Description."
);

// post to Facebook

try {
  $result = $facebook->api('/THE_PAGE_ID/feed', 'POST', $params);
  echo 'Successfully posted to Facebook';
} catch(Exception $e) {
  echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

This script sometimes works, sometimes not and the Exception is "Error validating access token: This may be because the user logged out or may be due to a system error." and sometimes the post is created as "/me" to The_Page_wall.
Any idea?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to post to a Facebook page with PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9225806/how-to-post-to-a-facebook-page-with-php)

Answer (score 1):

I guess you're using a so-called short-lived User Access Token. Get an overview of the different kinds of Access Tokens here:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/

I think you have two scenarios here:

1. Exchange you short-lived token via this endpoint to long-lived ones
   (60 days):
   https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/#extending
2. Use Page Access Tokens if you don't need the Posts to be posted by
   an actual User, but the Page itself:
   https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/#pagetokens