# Publish article to facebook from headless website using Facebook PHP SDK (for dummies)

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm really confused by the facebook api.
I have a website with a PHP based CMS installed. When articles are published on my website, I want to create a post on my facebook business page with a link back to this article.

**Now, to clarify:** this is a headless webserver which is to do the posting to facebook. There is no facebook login, no facebook user - only a server and a facebook page. The goal is for this to be self driven. Write/configure once and it works without any manual renewal of tokens or whatnots.

## Question (edited and refrased)

> How can I programmatically fetch an access token authorized to publish posts to my facebook page?

The procedure [I've seen proposed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9225806/how-to-post-to-a-facebook-page-with-php) is:

*First pass (auth as user, give app permissions (**pops up a dialog**), redirect back to page):*

```
GET https://www.facebook.com/v2.9/dialog/oauth?client_id=$APP_ID&redirect_uri=$MY_URL&state=&scope=publish_pages
```

*Second pass (get access token for app, redirect back to page):*

```
$CODE = $_REQUEST["code"]; // From facebook redirect process
GET https://graph.facebook.com/v2.9/oauth/access_token?client_id=$APP_ID&client_secret=$APP_SECRET&code=$CODE&redirect_uri=$MY_URL
```

But this will involve a user, which is something I do not have on my server. :-(

## This is what I have done so far, step-by-step

**Creating the app**

- I needed to [create a Facebook App](https://developers.facebook.com/apps) (`Add a New app` button).
- The app is setup under category `Apps for Pages`, and points to my website url.
- The `App ID` and `App Secret` is found under the `Settings` for your app.

**Getting the access token**

- Once the app was created, I went to [Facebook Graph Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer)
- In the header bar of graph explorer, I chose my newly created app from the `Application` dropdown.
- Right below, there is a large textfield with the label `Access Token`. In the dropdown to the right of this, I chose my facebook page from `Page access token`.
- From the same dropdown, I chose `Request publish_pages`, on which point I was prompted with a dialog wanting me to confirm.
- On the left, there is a "sidebar"-thingy with the text `Node: me` and a search field. I clicked on this, and selected `access_token` again.
- The `Submit` button then got me a JSON string with the relevant access token.

Now, this is a short-lived token (lives for about an hour). But even a long lived token will expire at some point. *The goal must be to find a way to programatically ask for a token when the code is instantiated.*

**Posting to facebook**

The code below works using the short-lived token.

```
$appId       = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
$appSecret   = 'yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy';
$accessToken = 'TheStringIGotFromGraphExplorer';

$fb = new \Facebook\Facebook([
    'app_id' => $appId,
    'app_secret' => $appSecret,
    'default_graph_version' => 'v2.9'
]);

try {
    // Returns a `Facebook\FacebookResponse` object
    $response = $fb->post('/me/feed', [
        'link'        => $article->getUrl(),
        'message'     => $article->getHeader(),
        'description' => $article->getIngress()
    ], $accessToken);
    $graphNode = $response->getGraphNode();
    $LOG->debug(__FILE__,__LINE__,"Posted with id: " . $graphNode['id']);
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
    $LOG->error(__FILE__,__LINE__,"Graph returned an error: " . $e->getMessage());
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
    $LOG->error(__FILE__,__LINE__,"Facebook SDK returned an error: " . $e->getMessage());
}
```

Comment: For fb page's user account and fb app's user account are same?

Comment: Yes, of course you need an app. But you don’t need to “connect” the page to the app; instead you simply have to ask a page admin for the necessary permissions during login.

Comment: @CBroe could you elaborate on that? Specifically the 'ask a page admin for the necessary permissions during login' part (as I am page admin, and don't know how to technically ask myself for permission). And perhaps put it as an answer?

Comment: Permissions are asked for via the login flow, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/requesting-and-revoking

Comment: @CBroe Not very specific. :-( Do I need to add code in order to do this? Do I need to go to a url and tick off checkboxes? The page you referred to describes the javascript, android and iOS APIs login flow. I'm using PHP sdk. I do not want to implement a login button on my webpage, as I want to post as a page to a page.

Comment: If you only need this for yourself, you can also get a token from a different place like Graph API explorer. Extending it can be done without actual coding, then you just have to perform the request manually in your browser.

Comment: @CBroe Ok, so in graph api explorer; I select a Page access token(?) from the dropdown list to the right of the textfield `Access token`? Then what? Submit will give me a json object. Do I copy the text in the `Access token` text field and use that in my code? Isn't that a "short-lived" token? If so, how do I get it to be a long-lived token or permanent token? And if I have a page access token, does this eliminate the need for a facebook app?

Comment: No, it doesn’t eliminate the need for an app. There is no talking to the API without an app. _“If so, how do I get it to be a long-lived token or permanent token?”_ – that is explained in the documentation in broad detail as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved!!

1. Go to [Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/)
2. Create an access token as described under `Getting the access token` in the original post, with permissions to publish on page.
3. Copy your access token, and paste it into [Access token debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/accesstoken) and click debug.
4. At the bottom of this screen, there's a button `Extend Access token`.

The token this button then delivers, is a token which **never** expires! Insert the new permanent token into the code above, and everything in the world smiles at you.

:-D <-- Me happy

Comment: Looks to me like the new token expires in 2 months. Guess they changed it.